# Haskell exceptions and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, exception, haskell

Based on SO question 13350164 [How do I test for an error in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350164/), I'm trying to write a unit test which asserts that given invalid input, a recursive function raises an exception. The approach I adopted works well for non-recursive functions (or when the first call raises the exception), but as soon as the exception occurs deeper in the call chain, the assertion fails.

I've read the excellent answers to question 6537766 [Haskell approaches to error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537766/) but unfortunately the advice is a bit too generic for this point of my learning curve. My guess is that the problem here is connected to lazy evaluation and non-pure testing code, but I'd appreciate an expert explanation.

Should I take a different approach to error handling in situations like this (e.g. `Maybe` or `Either`), or is there a reasonable fix for making the test case work correctly while using this style?

Here's the code I've come up with. The first two test cases succeed, but the third one fails with `"Received no exception, but was expecting exception: Negative item"`.

```
import Control.Exception (ErrorCall(ErrorCall), evaluate)
import Test.HUnit.Base  ((~?=), Test(TestCase, TestList))
import Test.HUnit.Text (runTestTT)
import Test.HUnit.Tools (assertRaises)

sumPositiveInts :: [Int] -> Int
sumPositiveInts [] = error "Empty list"
sumPositiveInts (x:[]) = x
sumPositiveInts (x:xs) | x >= 0 = x + sumPositiveInts xs
                       | otherwise = error "Negative item"

instance Eq ErrorCall where
    x == y = (show x) == (show y)

assertError msg ex f = 
    TestCase $ assertRaises msg (ErrorCall ex) $ evaluate f

tests = TestList [
  assertError "Empty" "Empty list" (sumPositiveInts ([]))
  , assertError "Negative head" "Negative item" (sumPositiveInts ([-1, -1]))
  , assertError "Negative second item" "Negative item" (sumPositiveInts ([1, -1]))
  ]   

main = runTestTT tests
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually just an error in `sumPositiveInts`. Your code does *not* do negativity checking when the only negative number is the last one in the list—the second branch doesn't include the check.

It's worth noting that the canonical way of writing recursion like yours would break the "emptiness" test out in order to avoid this bug. Generally, decomposing your solution into "sum" plus two guards will help to avoid errors.

---

I second the suggestion from [Haskell approaches to error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537766/) by the way. `Control.Exception` is much more difficult to reason about and learn and `error` should only be used to mark code branches which are impossible to achieve—I rather like some suggestions that it ought to have been called `impossible`.

To make the suggestion tangible, we can rebuild this example using `Maybe`. First, the unguarded function is built in:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

then we need to build the two guards (1) empty lists give `Nothing` and (2) lists containing negative numbers give `Nothing`.

```
emptyIsNothing :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
emptyIsNothing [] = Nothing
emptyIsNothing as = Just as

negativeGivesNothing :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
negativeGivesNothing xs | all (>= 0) xs = Just xs
                        | otherwise     = Nothing
```

and we can combine them as a monad

```
sumPositiveInts :: [a] -> Maybe a
sumPositiveInts xs = do xs1 <- emptyIsNothing xs
                        xs2 <- negativeGivesNothing xs1
                        return (sum xs2)
```

---

And then there are lots of idioms and reductions we can employ to make this code much easier to read and write (once you know the conventions!). Let me stress that **nothing after this point** is necessary nor terribly easy to understand. Learning it improves your ability to decompose functions and fluently think about FP, but I'm just jumping to the advanced stuff.

For instance, we can use "Monadic `(.)`" (which is also called Kleisli arrow composition) to write `sumPositiveInts`

```
sumPositiveInts :: [a] -> Maybe a
sumPositiveInts = emptyIsNothing >=> negativeGivesNothing >=> (return . sum)
```

and we can simplify both `emptyIsNothing` and `negativeGivesNothing` using a combinator

```
elseNothing :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Just a
pred `elseNothing` x | pred x    = Just x
                     | otherwise = Nothing

emptyIsNothing = elseNothing null

negativeGivesNothing = sequence . map (elseNothing (>= 0))
```

where `sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]` fails an entire list if any of the contained values are `Nothing`. We can actually go one step further since `sequence . map f` is a common idiom

```
negativeGivesNothing = mapM (elseNothing (>= 0))
```

---

So, in the end

```
sumPositives :: [a] -> Maybe a
sumPositives = elseNothing null 
               >=> mapM (elseNothing (>= 0))
               >=> return . sum
```

Comment: `Maybe` is a `MonadPlus`! Clearer to write `sumPositives xs = do { guard $ not (null xs) ; guard $ all (>0) xs ; return (sum xs) }` imo.

Comment: Yeah, I originally was going to go that way—re: all the times I use the word "guard" above. I was motivated to write it as a Kleisli composition after seeing the "pipeline" in my naïve monadic code, but it's definitely gratuitous.